# strophe.js http-bind error 504

Tags: ejabberd, haproxy, strophe

The following request is getting timed out frequently:

```
<body rid='57993057' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='1db840cbfd20e3922f594cc2017421a1858cca7a'><a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='9'/></body>
```

Console log shows:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am using ejabberd server with haproxy.